# How to get response header content-length when observing events in HttpClient.post() request? - Angular Http Client

Tags: angular, events, http-headers, progress-bar

```
generateReport(report: any) {
        return this.http.post(`Test`, JSON.stringify(report), 
       {headers:this.appGlobals.httpDocumentDownloadOptions.headers, 
       responseType: 'arraybuffer',  observe: 'events', reportProgress: true})
       .pipe(map(event => event),catchError(this.appGlobals.handleError),);
}
```

Comment: You can try `response.headers.get('content-length')` where response is what your get when your subscribe or pipe your `http.post()` method

Comment: it says  **Cannot read property 'get' of undefined **

Comment: the reponse am getting looks like {type: 1, loaded: 176, total: 176}

Comment: You need to pass `observe: response` instead of `observe: 'events'` and then `resp.headers.get('header-name')`, change header-name to whatever header you want to get.

Comment: I am observing events to know the file progress for showing the progress bar , if i observe response i wont be able to get event.loaded size

Comment: i mean to use httpProgressEvent am observing events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the [angular document for HttpProgressEvent](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpProgressEvent), you can get the number of bytes download/uploaded using `loaded` property of the event. You can't get the response headers when observing the `events` because what you are observing is an `HttpProgressEvent`, not [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse).

Comment: yes, without observing httpProgressEvent i cant get the small chuck of files getting downloading during the whole process of file download

Comment: I guess currently there is no way to get headers when observing `events` and most important it does not make sense to get response headers when observing `events`.

Comment: to show the progress bar i need the total size of the file and the small parts of file being downloaded so that i can compare both and show the percentage of file downloaded.

Comment: to fetch that total file size i wanted to fetch the content-length from header

Comment: You don't need content length, you can use `loaded` property from the event and do the calculation yourself. I'll update the answer.

Comment: if (response.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
                this.percent = Math.round(100 * response.loaded / response.total);
                console.log("percent-----", this.percent);
            }

Comment: Exactly. Please update your question so that it reflects the problem correctly.

Comment: i have done this but the problem is untill the http reaches download progress , the progress bar will be in 0% after it reached the downloadProgress the progress bar slides to 100 % very fast .... it doesnot look like progressing in small parts

Comment: That's a different problem. Maybe your file size is not large enough.